# Residue theorem and a function with two singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Supoose that

$f(z)=\frac{e^\frac{1}{z}}{1-2z}$.

Show that

$\oint_{\lvert z \rvert =1} f(z)dz = -\pi i$.

Now, I used the Laurent series of $e^\frac{1}{z}$ and the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1-2z}$ to compute the $a_{-1}$ and then by the multiplication of the two series we have that the $a_{-1}$ is a series which is basically $\frac{e^2-1}{2}$, which is the residue at zero. Also, the residue at half is just $e^2$. But if we add them and multiply by $2\pi i$ then we will not get the desired result. I cannot figure out what is my mistake. Any help  would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer is correct: you are out by a factor of two in your residue at $z=1/2$.

Comment: But why should there be a factor of two at half? Also, I think you mean a factor of minus two, right? If so, why minus? @messenger

Comment: Yes true, the minus as well. You need to multiply $f$ by $z-1/2$ and take the limit as $z\to 1/2$ to find the residue.  Multiplying by $z-1/2$ is not the same as multiplying by $1-2z$.

Comment: I see what you say, always did this in my mind though, good point, thanks! @messenger